# What can cause a thread to be throttled to 25% on Mac OS?

Tags: multithreading, macos, pthreads, throttling

I have a C++ application on Mac OS X. The app runs an event processing with the glfw library on the main thread and reads input and execute commands on a background C++ `std::thread`.
I am observing a frustrating phenomenon that I cannot explain so far.
If I make a call to a long running function on the background thread, initially that thread is using 100% of a core. But, after it has used a few seconds of CPU (10 seems to be the magic threshold), it gets throttled down to 25%.

If I start a computation run on a thread in the background before starting the glfw event processing loop (the event processing is essentially stuck waiting for events, as I don't even open a window), then it can use 100% for as long as it wants.

My biggest problem is that I have no idea what could be causing this nor how to figure it out. I've tested retrieving the pthread `sched_param` and changing the `sched_priority` from what seems to be default 31 to various values between 20 and 60 and it does not help.

I have identified one more condition for the phenomenon to happen:
The background thread has to have read from the terminal. It happens when I run the following background thread and enter a line for the computation to take place:

```
std::thread cmd([argc, argv, &scriptingRunner] {
      for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); ) {
          longComputation();
      }
```

Comment: Wild guess:  Perhaps App Nap is throttling your application to save energy.  To check, open the Activity Monitor program and right-click on the header of the processes table to bring up the context menu, and click on "App Nap" in the context menu to enable the App Nap column; then look at your process in the table and see if its value in the App Nap column switches to "Yes" when the fault occurs.

Comment: I am not see that menu in Activity Monitor. See my edit about the other condition for the phenomenon to happen.

Comment: See:  https://public.msli.com/lcs/jaf/appnap.png

Comment: I found that. Thanks. The 'Nap' is yes permanently. But could that be the thread from glfw which is waiting for event?
Now I am observing weirder behavior. The same thread that was only 25% has gone back to 100% most of the time since the computer went into 'dark mode'.... Not sure if it is related or not.
After restarting, I see again the 25% usage. 
After the discovery of the combination of main thread in glfw event process and the throttled thread having done input from the terminal, I'll create as trivial as possible a code that does that. If it shows that behavior, I'll publish it

Comment: @JeremyFriesner you are right.
The link you have is giving me a 404 error. Do you have another one? If you do, put it in an answer and I'll pick it as the right answer.
Some google search for some code yields other stackoverflow pages where you discussed related subjects. I also found some C++/C code but it will not compile in newer MacOS because of `objc_msgSend` not being declared with its arguments.

I totally disabled app nap on my computer, using `defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAppSleepDisabled -bool YES` and indeed the phenomenon does not happen again.

Comment: I used the code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686488/qapplication-is-lazy-or-making-other-threads-lazy-in-the-app and it does allow me to turn off app nap programmatically. @JeremyFriesner please post your explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps App Nap is throttling your application to save energy. To check, open the Activity Monitor program and right-click on the header of the processes table to bring up the context menu, and click on "App Nap" in the context menu to enable the App Nap column; then look at your process in the table and see if its value in the App Nap column switches to "Yes" when the fault occurs.

If you want to disable app nap for your app, see the code listed in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686488/qapplication-is-lazy-or-making-other-threads-lazy-in-the-app).

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I had been leaving this issue on the back burner for a while but it was time to address it and with your help, it got addressed in no time.